# In React how to make input check box ticked based on object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The check box function works fine and updating selected input value in to `this.state = { answers: [] };` At the same time the checkboxes doesn't show as selected on page load when page loading with

```
this.state = { 
  answers: [
    {
      questionID: 4, 
      answerValues: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/7jlq387686

```
{options.map(option => {
  var tick = checked.answerValues.find(answer => answer == option.id );
  return (
    <div className="form-check" key={option.id}>
      <label className="radio-inline" htmlFor={`${name}-${option.id}`}>
        <input
          name={name}
          id={`${name}-${option.id}`}
          type="checkbox"
          value={option.id}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, option.id)}
          checked={option.id == tick}
        />{" "}
        {option.value}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

There are two issues in the current snippet
1) When select from checkbox it works but the **preselected items are becoming unselected** 
2) when page load the checkbox doesn't work it says **Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1**

You miss to initialize the selected attribute corresponding with the checked prop:

```
constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);

   this.selected = this.answerValues
     .reduce((obj, curr) => ({ ...obj, [curr]: true }), {});

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }
```

Also add this getter to avoid errors when is not defined:

```
 get answerValues() {
   const { answerValues = [] } = this.props.checked || {};
   return answerValues;
 }
```

> Note: Also you can use directly [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to avoid this.

**Problem 2**

Instead of this line on render:

```
var tick = checked.answerValues.find(answer => answer == option.id);
```

Use:

```
var tick = this.answerValues.find(answer => answer == option.id);
```

**Clarifications**

1. On the **handleChange** from InputCheckbox you were saving the new `answerValues` as `Object.keys(this.selected)`, and at the beginning this selected was an empty object, this mean, that you was losing the first state. To keep the first state, you need to initialize the selected attribute.
2. Find of undefined was because there isn't an answers array yet, you can't fix this using the getter that I proposed, or also using defaultProps setting to a default value when this array is undefined.

*Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wnv238j1ww*

Comment: I saved the changes in the Sandbox solving the problem that you said, and updated the stackoverflow answer :)